# const retorna undefined ao utilizar o método getServerSideProps do Next.js

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, cookies, next.js

Olá, estou utilizando React com Next.js e utilizando o método nativo do Next.js, o getServerSideProps para recuperar os cookies do navegador.

Acontece que a desestruturação funciona para as primeiras const, mas não para a última.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async(ctx) => {
  const { level, currentExperience, challengesCompleted, user, userName, accumulatedExperience} = ctx.req.cookies;
  
  return {
    props: {
      level: Number(level ?? 1),
      currentExperience: Number(currentExperience ?? 0),
      challengesCompleted: Number(challengesCompleted ?? 0),      
      user: user || null,
      userName: userName || null,
      accumulatedExperience: Number(accumulatedExperience ?? 0)
    }
    
  };
}
```

No caso, **level, currentExperience e challengesCompleted** estão me retornando corretamente 0.
**user e userName**, corretamente null

Mas **accumulatedExperience** volta `undefined` e isso faz com que as operações matemáticas não sejam realizadas, pois me retorna **NaN**.

Alguem sabe o que pode ser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu, particularmente, não usaria o getServerSideProps para essa finalidade. Veja, essa função tem o intuito de fazer o Server Side Rendering (SSR), ou seja, quando você necessita processar algo no servidor antes de renderizar a página (ex.: pegar dados no banco de dados). Você pode utilizar outras estratégias do react para carregar essa informação quando o componente é montado. Uma saída seria utilizar o Hook useEffect

```
import {useEffect} from 'react'

const MeuApp = () =>{
  useEffect(()=>{
    //AQUI VC CAPTURA OS COCKIES
    },[]})
}
```

O useEffect é executado toda vez que o componente é montado e em conjunto com o useState, você poderá armazenar os dados do para serem usados no restante do código.

Comment: Acabei resolvendo aqui ainda com o getServerSideProps, porém vou fazer essa mudança já que não faz muito sentido capturar os cookies utilizando SSR. Obrigado.